# List area useless

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a list with three textfield. 
Under these three element I have an empty area (part of the list). 
I would like to '`delete`' that area.
I insert `.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())` at the end of the list but It didn't resolve at all the problem.

```
 VStack {

            fakebar

            //Lista

            List {
                TextField("Destinatario", text: $destinatario)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                TextField("Spedizione", text: $nomeRegalo)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                TextField("Costo", text: $costo)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            //                picker.padding(.horizontal, -40)



            }
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $isSheetOut) {
                self.actionSheet
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPhotoPickOut) {
                self.libPick
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

The liststyle modifier is modifying the sheet right now.

Use it directly on the list and after that the sheet and actionsheet.

```
List {
    // your code here
}.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

.actionSheet(isPresented: $isSheetOut) {
    self.actionSheet
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isPhotoPickOut) {
    self.libPick
}
```

That should resolve the issue.

If that’s not the problem but wanting to use the rest of the space for other stuff is, then yeah, it is kind of useless. You could think about other ways to present your TextFields and other UI..